# Bitmap Collision Detection(AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3

I have some bitmaps, one of the character and the other of spikes. I'm wanting to detect when the character bitmap collides with the spikes. The spike bitmaps are added to an array because there's so many of them. I've read things like this: http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2009/06/24/using-bitmapdata-hittest-for-collision-detection/

But that uses BitmapData and draws the bitmaps. Mine are embedded from PNGs. For example:

```
[Embed(source="../lib/NewChar.png")]
    public var CharImage:Class;

public var char:Bitmap = new CharImage();
```

How would I go about this or maybe I'm just missing something?

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to access the data using: `public var img:Bitmap = new CharImage(); var data:BitmapData = img.bitmapData`

Comment: Thanks Krister, I didn't know you could access it that way. I should be able to do it now. Thanks again :)

Comment: @KristerAndersson perhaps your suggestion should be posted as a simple answer which should be marked as a solution by Craig and would be easily spotted/found by the community in the future

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza - I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since embedded bitmaps is represented by the `BitmapAsset` class you should be able to access your embedded image data through the `bitmapData` property:

```
public var img:Bitmap = new CharImage();

var data:BitmapData = img.bitmapData;
```